OpenShift Operators clash over InstallModeType
OpenShift V4.12, have four operators installed in namespace openshift-operators, however they clash over there required InstallModeType. When the default global operator-group within the namespace is unaltered, two of the operators are in Failed mode with the error: Failed: AllNamespaces InstallModeType not supported, cannot configure to watch all namespaces.
The suggested solution is to add to the object group the following;
spec:
  targetNamespaces:
  - openshift-operators

Although the two operators that were in failed mode, become ok, the original two operators that were ok, then switch to being in Failed Mode, with the error: OwnNamespace InstallModeType not supported, cannot configure to watch own namespace.
I have tried to re-assign the filed operators to a different operator group, but that conflicted with the original global operator group in place, resulting in all operators reporting a failure.
